# Create sub folder from selected list of folder from my drive

Tags: python

How to create a subfolder in the selected list of dir.

My list of dir script is:

```
import  os
os.chdir(r"D:\0pramod\Project")
my_folder = os.getcwd()
list_entries = os.listdir(my_folder)
subfolder_names = ['Animation','Lighting','comp','roto','paint']

for subfolder_name in subfolder_names:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join('?', subfolder_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create `subfolder_names` inside each folder of `my_folder` you can simply do it with nested loops:

I would not suggest using `os.walk()` in here because it would iter over the `my_folder` and would give you `subfolder_names` inside the `my_folder`.

```
import  os
my_folder = r"D:\0pramod\Project"
list_entries = [os.path.join(my_folder, list_entry) for list_entry in os.listdir(my_folder)]
subfolder_names = ['Animation','Lighting','comp','roto','paint']

for subfolder_name in subfolder_names:
    for list_entry in list_entries:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(list_entry, subfolder_name))
```

Comment: how to create subfolder in subfolder_names [comp] dir?

Comment: @PramodPandey What do you mean exactly? What is `subfolder`?

Comment: I require one more folder inside comp director

Comment: @PramodPandey Are you saying that you need all `subfolder_name` list folders inside each of them? e.g you would have `Animation`, `Lighting`, etc on `Animation` and goes on for other list members.

Comment: how to add other list there?